# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when delete from three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm try to use inner join to delete from three tables

```
DELETE ALLFCS, DATASHARINGS, DATAOWNERSHIP FROM ALLFCS INNER JOIN DATASHARINGS INNER JOIN DATAOWNERSHIP
WHERE ALLFCS.FCID = DATASHARINGS.FKFCID AND DATASHARINGS.FKFCID = DATAOWNERSHIP.FKFCID AND ALLFCS.FCID= '226' ;
```

but the following error comes

```
Error starting at line : 16 in command -
DELETE ALLFCS, DATASHARINGS, DATAOWNERSHIP FROM ALLFCS INNER JOIN DATASHARINGS INNER JOIN DATAOWNERSHIP
WHERE ALLFCS.FCID = DATASHARINGS.FKFCID AND DATASHARINGS.FKFCID = DATAOWNERSHIP.FKFCID AND ALLFCS.FCID= '226' 
Error at Command Line : 16 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help?>

Comment: why are you using sql-server and mysql as tags ?? Is it Oracle only related, isn't it ?

Comment: Duplicate I posted is 2 years old why do you think you can multi table delete in oracle?

Comment: @P.Salmon I want to delete from one statement only

Comment: A DELETE statement can only delete from a single table.

Comment: There are examples in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DELETE.html). Nothing on that page suggests your syntax is valid.